# How to combine \color and \MakeUppercase

Tags: color

I've been tinkering with a `.cls` file for a bit that defines what my "sections" look like. It looks like this at the moment:

```
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip  
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  {\color{blue} {\bf #1}} % MY LINE
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

I added using the color package and the line with the comment `MY LINE` after a while and it works as expected (It bolds and colors the section title blue). The line before it bolds it and capitalizes it, and so the section title appears twice. I've been trying to combine those into one, with, for example:

```
{\color{blue} {\MakeUpperCase {\bf #1}}
```

but the above does not work. What would be the correct way of doing so?

Comment: `\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}`

Comment: wow never heard of \bfseries but this worked!

Comment: @PalaceChan `\bfseries` is unrelated to your question that was just a correction for `\bf` which should not be used (and is not defined by default) in latex. Also note that you are missing `%` from ends of lines `\MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title` _does not work_ to hide the white space you need to remove the space before the `%`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the environment should do, but here's the correct way to get an uppercase blue title in boldface:

```
\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

The `\bf` declaration has been deprecated for twenty years; the right declaration to use is `\bfseries`; in your case I'd also add `\normalfont` to avoid the outside font having any influence. In any case, this should go outside `\MakeUppercase`.

So the definition should probably be

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{% 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip  
  \textcolor{blue}{\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}% Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{% List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}% Margin within the section
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \end{list}%
}
```

Note the correct usage of `%` at the end of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your example line

```
{\color{blue} {\MakeUpperCase {\bf #1}}
```

includes two mistakes: the braces don't match (note, there is extra `{`) and the control sequence `\MakeUpperCase` includes capital `C`. After removing these two mistakes your idea is working:

```
 {\color{blue} \MakeUppercase {\bf #1}}
```